# quick question: clear an attribute of a model in django

Tags: python, django, model

i think this is a pretty easy question for you.
I want to clear an attribute of a django-model.

If i have something like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):   
     name = models.TextField()  
     pages = models.IntegerField()  
     img = models.ImageField()
```

In an abstract function i want to clear an attribute, but at that time i don't know what type the field has. So examples would be `name=""`, `pages=0` or `img=None`.. Is there a way to do it in a generic way? I search something like `SET_TO_EMPTY(book,"pages")`

Do you know a function like that?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a clean way of doing it. However, assuming you've set a default value (which you don't have) you can do it like this:

```
book.img = book._meta.get_field('img').default
```

Do note that your current model won't allow a `None` value. To allow those you have to set `null=True` and `blank=True`. For `pages` you need a `default=0`.